# Getting the correct version of Pmw to install

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x

**Problem:**

I'd like to install Pmw 2.0.0 (project page [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pmw/2.0.1)) so that I can use it with tkinter in python3. The setup script from the package detects which version of python you're using and installs the version that is appropriate for your system (Ubuntu 15 in my case). I can't find any references to switches to make it install the 2.0.0 instead of 1.3.3(the Python 2.7 version), nor have I been able to get the script to install to the python3 libraries.

**What I've done so far:**

I've changed the python version detector in the setup script from

```
if sys.version_info[0]<3:
     version='2.0.0' # really '1.3.3'
     packages=['Pmw', 'Pmw.Pmw_1_3_3', 'Pmw.Pmw_1_3_3.lib',]
```

to

```
if sys.version_info[0]<2:
     version='2.0.0' # really '1.3.3'
     packages=['Pmw', 'Pmw.Pmw_1_3_3', 'Pmw.Pmw_1_3_3.lib',]
```

to attempt to force the installer to default to the python3 version, which it does, but it installs them in the python2.7 libraries (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distpackages).

**What I want to do:**

I'm looking for a way to force the installer to put the 3.4-compatible package into the python3 libraries. If that means getting it to install both packages in their respective correct directories, that's fine, too. I'm stumped about what to try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by RazZiel on AskUbuntu:

[Link here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677611/getting-a-setup-script-to-install-in-the-correct-library-destination-pmw-2-0-0/677625#677625)

Instead of using the command `sudo python setup.py build` and then `sudo python setup.py install`, I should have been using `python3` to execute the setup script. I've managed to outthink myself pretty badly on this one.